# alternative to 'this.variable' inside constructor functions's methods

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to write a constructor function that would make an object chock full of complex methods. These methods process variables of their parents as-well as call on sibling methods. Here's the best example I can give you. It's for an improvised web-based console.

```
function ConsoleCont(type,instace){
    this.type=type;
    this.input=$('conI');//input type=text
    this.output=$('conO');//textarea
    this.commandRecall=new Array;
    //event listeners for enter-key to this.send(), etc.
    this.send=function(){
        if(this.input.value){this.commandRecall.push(this.input.value);}
        this.consoleConcat("> "+this.input.value);
        /*Code to send via AJAX*/
        this.input.value="";
    }
    this.consoleConcat=function(command){
        /*code to push to Textarea*/
    }
    this.receive=function(latestLine){
        this.consoleConcat(latestLine)
    }
}
```

Now I find myself needing to type "this." for everything I reference within the object; is there anyway to have it assume 'this.' (like C++'s `using namespace` or something) or perhaps my methods for this a bit inefficient? I'm not looking for any Jquery solutions, I had predefined `$('');` myself, incase you caught that.

Comment: If your functions are indented to be public, you should put them on the function object's prototype so you're not defining them for every object instance that is created.

Comment: An important consideration of mine, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ditch a few `this`'s in your code, as far as I can see:

```
function ConsoleCont(type,instace) {
//                             ^did you mean instance?
    // both input/output are assigned to a fixed value, so they seem
    // not specific to an instance, hence can be ('static'-like) variables
    var input  = $('conI'), 
        output = $('conO'); 

    // these are really local (instance) properties
    this.type  = type;
    this.commandRecall = [];

    // the event listener(s) can be added to the constructors prototype
    if (!ConsoleCont.prototype.send){
     var proto = ConsoleCont.prototype;
     proto.send = function(){
        if(input.value){
           this.commandRecall.push(this.input.value);
        }
        consoleConcat("> "+this.input.value);
        /*Code to send via AJAX*/
        this.input.value = "";
     };
    }

    // if not used as public methods, these methods can be 
    // assigned and used within the current scope ('private')
    function consoleConcat(command){
        /*code to push to Textarea*/
    }

    function receive(latestLine){
        consoleConcat(latestLine)
    }
}
```

So, checking your code for the necessity of values or functions being properties can reduce the number of `this`'s. The only other mechanism to reduce typing all `this` all over may indeed be using `with`, but that has some pitfalls, as [Douglas Crockford explained here](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the word `with` will help you:

```
function ConsoleCont(type,instace)
{
  with(this)
  {
    type=type;
    input = $('conI');
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/34trZ/2/

Comment: Names in a `with` block are only bound to the given object if that object already a property with that name. Your example mangles the global object; it does not set properties on `this`.

Comment: But ... also read http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/

Comment: Using of `with` is generally discouraged.

Comment: @一二三: Check out this example: http://jsfiddle.net/34trZ/
@Jiri: Yes, I don't recommend `with` but the OP asked for it.

Comment: Your example still mangles the global object; and because you don't use it as a constructor, `this` refers to `window`. See: http://jsfiddle.net/xdtf9/

Answer (score 0):

To bring it to the point: it is **not possible** to avoid typing `this` when refering to object properties in the constructor function for this object. Of course, local variables and functions are not qualified with `this.`.